# PageSpeed ScriptManager optimization ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, optimization, asp.net-ajax, pagespeed, scriptmanager

PageSpeed indicates this files need to be defered:

```
https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.5/6/MicrosoftAjax.js (88.5 Ko)
https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/.../MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js (36.3 Ko)
https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.5.1/1/WebForms.js (14.6 Ko)
```

These files are called by the ScriptManager. How can I optimize this ?

```
<asp:ScriptManager LoadScriptsBeforeUI="false" EnableCdn="true" ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

I tried :

```
<asp:ScriptManager SupportsPartialRendering="true" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="false" EnableCdn="true" ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

But it seems to do nothing.
I tried

```
<asp:ScriptManager SupportsPartialRendering="false" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="false" EnableCdn="true" ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

and I only have 1 file to optimize

```
https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.5/6/MicrosoftAjax.js (88.5 Ko)
```

I read the documentation of LoadScriptsBeforeUI, EnableCdn and SupportsPartialRendering but I don't really understand. So I just tried randomly and have better results.

So the question is how can I "defer" this last file.

Edit :
I don't understand why when I am in a page needing a connection (log in), there's this file to optimize too :

```
.../WebResource.axd?... (14.6 Ko)
```

All pages are using my base.master where you can find the ScriptManager and no scripts are added.